# What does @ do in this php?

Tags: php

```
// Get the image information and display the image:
    if ($image = @getimagesize ("../uploads/$pid")) {
        echo "<div align=\"center\"><img src=\"show_image.php?image=$pid&name=" . urlencode($row['image_name']) . "\" $image[3] alt=\"{$row['print_name']}\" /></div>\n";   
    } else {
        echo "<div align=\"center\">No image available.</div>\n"; 
    }
```

What does @ do in @getimagesize?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It stops errors from being displayed and/or being logged from that specific function call.

Answer (score 17):

It is an [Error Control Operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php), that will mask (prevent from being displayed) any error the `getimagesize` function could generate.

It it generally not considered a good practice to use it : it makes your code really harder to debug *(if there is an error, you won't know about it)* :

> Currently the "@" error-control
> operator prefix will even disable
> error reporting for critical errors
> that will terminate script execution.
> Among other things, this means that if
> you use "@" to suppress errors from a
> certain function and either it isn't
> available or has been mistyped, the
> script will die right there with no
> indication as to why.

There is even a PHP extension, called [scream](http://pecl.php.net/package/scream), that disables this operator -- can be pretty useful when you are maintaintaing an apllication that used this operator a lot...

Generally, it is better to set [`error_reporting`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) ([see also](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)) level and [`display_errors`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) so that errors are displayed in development, and not in production -- that's way more useful that just always hiding them !

Answer (score 0):

It suppress errors to appear. If the command you are invoking has an error or a warning to state, you will not get any printout in the page. You can also see it used with mysql_* routines.